# Call methods parallel and combine results

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a MainMethod which needs to call two methods Method1 and Method2 parallel. Both of them will return list of Employee but from different database. I need to call them parallel and then combine the results of Method1 and Method2 in MainMethod and then return result to the caller of MainMethod.

I greatly appreciate if people can tell what must be signatures of methods and what code I need to write I mean async/await keywords.

Comment: Why do you "need" them parallel?  Here's one duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320491/simplest-way-to-run-three-methods-in-parallel-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DStanley - Parallel.Invoke is not the way to collect results.

Comment: @DStanley Nor is it guaranteed to run in parallel.

Comment: The code is not garuanteed to run at all - make sure that if you make tasks using `new Task` to call `Task.Start`. Also, since you lock while performing the get method, the long running parts will likely _not_ run in parallel, though it will get a proper result.

Comment: @Aravol . : I updated my question/code. I just want to lock so that only one thread access ints to add results. Is that wrong?

Comment: This lock is technically correct in that it prevents multiaccess to the results. However, as both my and @HenkHolterman do in our answerrs, it's better for each task to run, have result, and then concatenate those results, instead of adding to a singularized buffer inline. Less locking, fewer gotchas (if your query returns an `IEnumerable<>`, it may not actually execute until iterated,and this still do it's work in the lock).

Comment: You should not be editing the answer into the questions.  Answers belong in the answers.

Comment: I updated my question and pasted my code. Thanks to Henk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run them as 2 `Task<T>`s. The Result property takes care of the waiting. Approximately:

```
// untested 
Task<List<Employee>> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1());
Task<List<Employee>> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2());

var result = t1.Result.Concat(t2.Result);
```

Comment: Henk... can you please tell me what must be signature of Method1() or Method2() and how I can return results from them and any async/await keywords I need to use.

Comment: They just need to return `List<Employee>`. No await here.

Comment: Henk.. please see my updates question. I added a sample code that I wrote. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it looks correct but neither short nor efficient. What went wrong with the Task<T> approach?

Comment: I donot know why my question was edited. It clearly has the complete code what I wrote so that others can use it. But this is the signature of my methods private static List<Employee> Method1() and private static List<Employee> Method2()

Comment: Servy regarded it an answer. You intended it as a follow-up but it's different enough to be a separate question. We like questions short and on topic here, not long threads.

Answer (score 3):

Using a bit more shorthand...

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> MainMethod()
{
    // Await when all to get an array of result sets after all of then have finished
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => Method1()), // Note that this leaves room for parameters to Method1...
        Task.Run(Method2)          // While this shorthands if there are no parameters
        // Any further method calls can go here as more Task.Run calls
        );

    // Simply select many over the result sets to get each result
    return results.SelectMany(r => r);
}
```

for signature reference, this uses the following .NET functions:

- [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) (as an extension method)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is signature of Method1() and Method2(). Can you please write full code.

Comment: `Method1` and `Method2` are simply examples, taken from the original writing of this question. I can add a signatyure, though