# how to call two methods in windows service simultaneously C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to create windows service with two method

1. call the **com port** and wait for response
2. call the **web-service** and wait for response

Whenever received an answer from either of them, send the response to the Software that calls Windows service

My question is how track the two methods for response simultaneously

Comment: You may refer to this similar question: [Simplest way to run three methods in parallel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320491/simplest-way-to-run-three-methods-in-parallel-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @VincentLim hi tnx for your time, can i use thread for this?

Comment: @EricSchaefer no, i want Whenever received an answer from either of them the windows-service send back the response, not wait for that two to complete, because it always get the responcse from one of them